# Integrate a by-part power law

Tags: fourier-transform, gamma-function, residue-calculus, correlation

A few days ago I came across a paper (don't remember the name) that claimed that the auto-correlation function of a process defined by a "by-part" power-law (like here : [PSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUnSE.png)), which can be described by several exponents, also follows a power-law.

Now, the autoccorelation function is defined as the inverse fourier transform of the power-spectral density, so I wanted to see if this claim is true by calculating it myself. We know, for instance, that this is true for a pure power law since the fourier transform : 
$$\hat f(t)=\int_0^\infty t^\alpha e^{i\omega t}d\omega.$$  is 
$$(-it)^{-(\alpha+1)}\Gamma(\alpha+1).$$
So it might be the case for a "by-part" example. I tried computing the fourier transform myself, of the following : 
$$\hat f(t)=\int_0^{w_c} t^{\alpha_1} e^{-i\omega t}d\omega + \int_{w_c}^\infty t^{\alpha_2} e^{-i\omega t}d\omega.$$
With ${w_c}$ being the point where the slope exponent changes, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ being the two exponents. 
I tried changing the variables to get close to a gamme function without succes and I also tried solving them with help of the residue theorem without better success...

Does anyone has an idea how I can solve this integral ?

Comment: Your function is not $L^1$, and so its Fourier transform is not given by an integral; it is given by [Schwartz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions).

Comment: Don't know but maybe with the "incomplete lower/upper gamma function" ?